# Rails: Modeling complex associations to fit real-world relationships between generations of animals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**Using Rails 3.1.1**

I'm modeling associations between Animals (individual dogs) and Litters (groups of offspring).  It gets complicated because an animal is both born into a litter ***and*** can parent many litters (as either a mother ***or*** a father).

Here are the relevant parts of my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do

  create_table "animals", :force => true do |t|
    ...
    t.integer  "litter_id"
    t.string   "sex"
    ...
  end

  create_table "litters", :force => true do |t|
    ...
    t.integer  "father_id"
    t.integer  "mother_id"
    ...
  end
end
```

And here are the appropriate models, with what I think could work as associations:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :litter
  has_many   :litters, :foreign_key => :father_id
  has_many   :litters, :foreign_key => :mother_id
  has_one    :father,  :through => :litter, :foreign_key => :father_id
  has_one    :mother,  :through => :litter, :foreign_key => :mother_id
  ...
end

class Litter < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many   :animals
  belongs_to :father, :class_name => 'Animal'
  belongs_to :mother, :class_name => 'Animal'    
  ...
end
```

---

**Will I run into problems if I double up on `belongs_to` and `has_many` associations in their respective models?  If so, how can I properly model those associations?**

---

**UPDATE:** *As mentioned in a comment below, I'm using the Litter model to track about 10 attributes that are common to every Animal in that Litter.  This software will be run by dog breeders, so the Litter is itself a relevant unit from several standpoints, and will carry a lot of weight (beyond parent/child relationships) when it comes to surfacing data in views.*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just treat all dogs as animals.

Each animal will go something like this (untested):

```
belongs_to :mother, :class_name => "Animal", :foreign_key => "mother_id"
belongs_to :father, :class_name => "Animal", :foreign_key => "father_id"
has_many :children, :through => :animals # not sure if you need a foreign key specification here
```

animals table:

```
id | mother_id | father_id
```

The oldest ancestor that you keep track of won't have parents, so their `mother_id` and `father_id` will be nil.

The only reason I can see for keeping track of the `litter_id` is to keep track of siblings, which might be something you need. In that case you can have the litter be its own object, as in your example, or you can do a simple check like:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def is_sibling_of(animal)
     self.mother == animal.mother
  end

  ...    
end
```

...or an object `scope` (was called `named_scope` previous to Rails3):

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  scope :siblings, lambda {|animal| {:conditions => ["id not in (?) AND mother_id = ?", animal.id, animal.mother.id} }

  ...
end
```

Which would give you a list of all siblings of the specified animal, not including the animal itself.

Comment: There are reasons (outside the scope of this question) that I want to track data about Litters anyway.  Given that there will be a Litter model anyway, is it still best to repeat the mother/father combo that every puppy in that litter shares?  (That doesn't strike me as a very normal data structure, since updating the father of a litter, for instance, would then require updating the record of each Animal in that Litter... but I'm no expert.)

Comment: I guess that depends on how much your software model reflects the real world/which situations you want to model. I mean, when does your father ever change? It would be set upon creation (birth) of the animals, and wouldn't ever change, correct? We're not talking divorces, step-dog-fathers, and the like, I presume? I suppose it's possible to know a dog is alive, but not know who its father is (which means it would start out as `nil` and eventually change to something), so in that case, yes, having the `litter` as an intermediate object is totally valid.

Comment: The father wouldn't necessarily be the thing that changes--it was just an attribute that happened to be in the scope of the question that *could* change.  Litter columns will include things such as  `expected_birth_date`, `breed_id`, `notes`, et cetera (not all of which will change, obviously, but a few of which might).  There are 10 columns in my `litters` table, so that's a lot of repeating data that's _always_ common across _all_ of the `animals` in a given litter.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay here, but I was thinking about this problem more, and found the following discussion, which may or may not be helpful. http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=1248 It's largely a re-stating of what I have above, but with a slightly modified perspective and some extra discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing any of Ruby, Rails or ActiveRecord, still I think what you need a Graph library (the data-structure not the picture) and a persistence layer which stores it for you. [Here](http://rgl.rubyforge.org/rgl/index.html) is a Ruby Graph library, persistence is on you.

Comment: yeah, just happened to see this one at the top of the list when I clicked on to the home site. Never mind me if @normalocity is correct. JAPH

Comment: or as he deleted the comment, maybe I should stand my ground (wow I feel out of place :-P)